# Como posso criar uma query com ordenação alternada em rails 5?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Tenho a seguinte formatação no meu banco de dados

Produtos
 - Nome
 - Id Loja

com os seguintes registros

---

produto 1 - Loja 1
produto 2 - Loja 1
produto 3 - Loja 3
produto 4 - Loja 1
produto 5 - Loja 2
produto 6 - Loja 2
produto 7 - Loja 1
produto 8 - Loja 1
produto 9 - Loja 3
produto 10- Loja 3

---

quero fazer uma query onde eu trago o resultado alternando pelo "Id Loja", algo que ficasse no seguinte formato:

---

produto 1 - Loja 1
produto 5 - Loja 2
produto 3 - Loja 3
produto 2 - Loja 1
produto 6 - Loja 2
produto 9 - Loja 3
produto 4 - Loja 1
produto 10- Loja 3
produto 7 - Loja 1
produto 8 - Loja 1

Essa listagem vai ser paginada ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar o método "order" que seu model já herda do ActiveRecord:

```
Produto.order("loja_id asc, nome asc")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Orlando, mas isso não vai me ajudar, pois preciso que o resultado da query venha alternado pelo "ID Loja", usando o order como você mencionou, pode ser que venha apenas produtos da mesma loja em sequencia.